# Make a div the same width as its preceding sibling

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I have the following structure that I can't change to add or remove elements:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="image.png">
  <div class="caption">A very long caption that sometimes is much wider than the preceding image.</div>
</div>
```

I need to display the caption below the image while preserving the original image size, without stretching the image. If the caption is narrower than the `img` everything works well, but if the caption is wider than the image I need it to break to as many lines as needed after reaching the width of the preceding image. Image size can't be hard coded.

I need to achieve this, either using flex or sass, no javascript.

[image: I need to achieve this, either using flex or sass, no javascript.]